# Will iTextSharp version 5.5.2 run with C#, .net version 3.5 code?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to merge mutiple pdf files into one pdf. My code is using .net and C# version 3.5.

From what I have read here in StackOverflow and elsewhere, iTextSharp seems to be most highly recommended pdf file manipulation utility.

Will the latest version of iTextSharp on sourceforge.net, I think it is 5.5.2, work with my old code or should I try to download an earlier version of iTextSharp?

Comment: Why the -1? If someone has tried this why can't I learn from their experience?

Comment: Yes, it definitely will.

Comment: The officially built binary is still actually compiled against the 2.0 framework so as others have said, there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in the readme and on stack, you should have no problem with 5.5.2. At our company we still use 5.1 or 5.2 and I guarantee that works in C# 3.5.